# How to slidedown/slideup a layout from the bottom of screen on Scroll?

Tags: android, animation, scrollview

I need to slide down a layout while scrolling and slide up when scrolling is stopped. I tried doing it
with the below code, but facing some issue. The problem is that for the first time when i scroll, it works perfectly.

But when i try to scroll again, the animation doest work, it sort of flickers.
Attached the below code.

PLease let me know where i am going wrong.

scrollviewDetails = (ScrollView) fragmentView.findViewById( R.id.sv_details );
        scrollviewDetails .setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener( ) {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ) {
            switch ( event.getAction( ) ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.e( "SCROLL", "ACTION_SCROLL slidingDown==" +slidingDown );
                    if(!slidingDown){
                        flActionNow.clearAnimation( );
                        slidingDown = true;
                        slidingUp = false;
                        flActionNow.setAnimation( slideDown );
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.e( "SCROLL", "ACTION_DOWN" );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.e( "SCROLL", "SCROLL_STOP slidingUp==" +slidingUp );
                    if(!slidingUp){
                        flActionNow.clearAnimation( );
                        slidingUp = true;
                        slidingDown = false;
                       flActionNow.setAnimation( slideUp );
                    }
                   break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );
```

SLIDE DOWN ANIM:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <translate
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:fromYDelta="0%p"
       android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

SLIDE UP ANIM:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fromYDelta="75%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake I did! using startAnimation instead of setAnimation worked ! :)